# What is an alternative to location.reload() as Codepen doesn't allow this?

Tags: javascript, codepen

I'm using this in one of my pens, but it doesn't work

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
        location.reload();
    }
);
```

This gives an error: `pen.js:223 Uncaught TypeError: location.removedByCodePen is not a function`

I tried referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958553/reload-on-click-function-not-working-in-javascript) post on SO, but both the solutions mentioned there doesn't work, it gives some other error.

```
Refused to display " " in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Comment: Don't use Codepen?

Comment: I would not showcase to anyone a project that triggers a website reload() whenever a "resize" event triggers. PS: https://pages.github.com/

Comment: You can create a standalone project and host it somewhere. However, looking at the code, this sounds a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - reloading the page on resize seems like a heavy handed workaround.

Comment: don't post links to discord messages, as they don't work if one isnt a member of given channel and they can be easily edited and will make your question meaningless in the future

Comment: first of all why would you reload a page whenever the resize event happens ?

Answer (score 1):

One option that might be available, is instead of reloading the page, which can't be done, is to go back in history. `history.go(0);` can be used, where 0 indicates the amount of pages to go back. `history.go(-1);` Would go back one page for example.